# Microsoft Office has stopped working

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-access

Every time I try to run MS Word,Excel, PP, OneNote (2007), it crashes. I get:

> microsoft office has stopped working..

Safe mode also doesn't run. I have windows server 2008 (32bits) and MS products used to work some time before. How to fix it?

Comment: Please post this to superuser.com, this is not a programming question.

Comment: You could try looking at the problem details in the Action Center. Open the solution, click "view all problems this applies to" and open the technical details. Perhaps Googling something there (or posting it here) will yield some more useful information.

Answer (score 3):

Have you attempted a Repair from Add Remove programs?  That often resolves issues like corrupt files.  Open Add/Remove and click on MS Office 2007 and then select Change and then Repair

Answer (score 0):

You could record file and Registry accesses during the start of e.g. Word using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx). Maybe that will give you a hint what goes wrong.

However, as the problem seems to occur with all Office applications, I would definitely try to repair the installation as suggested by DaveM.